# Can't create new simulator in xcode 9 beta

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta

I have just installed xcode 9.0 beta. And I'm trying create a new simulator, but it no response when I click Create button (image below). Any idea?

[image]

Comment: It was the same issue with Xcode 7, Xcode 8.0, Xcode 8.1, Xcode 8.2, Xcode 8.3, ... close and restart Xcode after installing it.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541710/5912335 .... This would solve your issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Restart xcode resolved my issue.