# Xcode 9.3.1 components list empty, can't download iOS 10 simulators

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running Xcode 9.3.1 (9E501) and my Components list is empty, preventing me from downloading iOS 10 simulators.

I have tried:

- Deleting the following locations and re-installing Xcode:

/Applications/Xcode.app

/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode

~/Library/Developer/

- Manually deleting all my iOS simulators
- Nothing I tried seems to work.  I am running a non-admin user and installed Xcode using the admin user, if that makes any difference. Project is universal, deployment target is 10.3 (don't think that should matter).

[image: Empty components list]

Comment: In Xcode, the menu item Windows > Devices & Simulators, do you see anything listed under Simulators? If you click the `+` button in the bottom-left corner of that Simulator list (even if the list is empty) do you get any options for installing new simulators?

Comment: Try this answer. Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541710/5912335

Comment: @christopherdrum - Yeah there are some simulators for iOS 11.  None for iOS 10.  When I click add, I can only add iOS 11 simulators.  There's an option to download additional simulators, which takes me to the empty Components page in my original post. I have also tried to delete all the simulators and re-install but Components page is still empty.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh - I tried deleting the whole Developer folder which contains the folder in the link, but it didn't work.  I tried deleting that one folder and restarting xcode but same effect

Comment: Preferences > Accounts shows a working developer account? No problems, or warning flags, etc? Perhaps delete your account from there and re-add it, and see if Xcode gets its head on straight about your ability to query/download from the Developer portal.

Comment: @christopherdrum - yeah working dev account, tried to remove and re-add.  It's a non-expired account that has published apps.  Only 1 account registered.  I found a workaround by using command line.

Comment: Same here... see also: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/102783. Seems to be an authentication issue when XCode tries to get the list of sims. Maybe you should also submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @miliu - did you ever find a way to resolve this without manually installing everything?  I have the same problem with Xcode 11.2.1 Beta that I downloaded.

Comment: @nurider - I don't think so, but then again this was a year and a half ago and my memory is pretty bad these days.

Comment: Still an issue in Xcode 12.0.1 :(

Comment: The issue has come up again in Xcode 12.0.1 The apple forums as usual have no answer Apparently IOS 13.7 was crashing and thus the Apple App Review team has rejected the build The only way around now is using gem

Comment: I don't want to be the "same here" guy but yeah, this is happening to me in XCode 12.0.1.

Comment: It happens in Version 12.2 (12B45b) too.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to install iOS 10.3.1 manually via command line.  Still not able to get Components to show anything.

```sh
# Install xcode-install command line tools
gem install xcode-install

# Use xcversion to install additional iOS versions
xcversion simulators --install='iOS 10.3.1'
```

Comment: Wow. so, this gem also installed 61 other gems, including: googleauth, google-api-client, google-cloud-env, google-cloud-errors, google-cloud-core, rake, digest-crc, google-cloud-storage, emoji_regex, jmespath, aws-partitions, aws-eventstream, aws-sigv4, aws-sdk-core, aws-sdk-kms, aws-sdk-s3, fastlane. Is all this stuff really needed to simply download simulator SDKs? :)