# How to enable/disable “Show as run destination” for all simulators

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to toggle the “*Show as run destination*” flag for multiple iOS simulators instead of changing it one by one in the "*Device and Simulators*" window?
Is there a **command line** with that purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I decided to find it by myself using [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch). BTW, it's really useful for this kind of situations. By monitoring the changes of file while *toggling* the "*Show as run destination*" flag, I found out that Xcode was changing the **`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`** file

After some analysis, I noticed the key that I needed to change to achieve what I had in mind. The key is **`DVTIgnoredDevices`** and it holds an array of simulators. So, each simulator UUID in that list will be ignored in Xcode.

Now, I can change the `DVTIgnoredDevices` key using [`defaults`](https://ss64.com/osx/defaults.html) command line tool specifying the needed value type:

> **-array** Allows the user to specify an array as the value for the given preference key:
>
> ```
> defaults write somedomain preferenceKey -array element1 element2 element3
> ```
>
> The specified array overwrites the value of the key if the key was present at the time of the write. If the key was not present, it is created with the new value.

**Example:**

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTIgnoredDevices '(
  "80E16DBC-2FE5-48AC-8A44-1F5DEFA00EA7",
  "B8C4D5FF-8F1A-4895-BD16-CCAFECD71098"
)'
```

After setting the `DVTIgnoredDevices` key, you need to clean the `DerivedData` folder and restart Xcode. To clean the `DerivedData` folder, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541710/3641812) answer or just run the shortcut `shift+alt+cmd+k` (that's what I usually do).

Tested on Xcode Version 9.4 (9F1027a).

**UPDATE:**

I usually like to have just a couple of Simulators in the list, so I decided to do a script using `instruments -s devices` and add all the current Simulators to the `DVTIgnoredDevices` key. Then I chose which simulator(s) will be shown

**Xcode-hide-all-iPhone-simulators.sh**

```
simulatorsIdentifiers=$(instruments -s devices |
  grep -o "iPhone .* (.*) \[.*\]" | #only iPhone
  grep -o "\[.*\]" | #only UUID
  sed "s/^\[\(.*\)\]$/\1/" | #remove square brackets
  sed 's/^/"/;$!s/$/"/;$s/$/"/' | #add quotes
  sed '$!s/$/,/' #add comma to separate each element
)

arrayOfSimulatorsIdentifiers=($(echo "$simulatorsIdentifiers" | tr ',' '\n'))

# Add simulators to DVTIgnoredDevices
echo "${#arrayOfSimulatorsIdentifiers[@]}"
for index in "${!arrayOfSimulatorsIdentifiers[@]}"
do
    echo "$index Adding: ${arrayOfSimulatorsIdentifiers[index]}"
done

defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTIgnoredDevices -array ${arrayOfSimulatorsIdentifiers[@]}
```

[Gist file](https://gist.github.com/ricardopereira/adae5038191ac9f8d4ee03c23fde1b8c)

Comment: Thank you, sir. I hid all simulators (just removed the second line of your snippet)

Comment: I got really excited when I saw this, but it doesn't seem to work in Xcode 10.3.

Comment: I just deleted the DerivedData and it worked! Thank you sir